# No 'sharing' tab when attempting to connect laptop with xbox 360

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, bridge, xbox360

I am using a Sony Vaio Series SR, Windows Vista and have followed a number of forums and threads on how to resolve the issue. The issue is that when I go to **Control Panel** > **Network and Sharing Center** > **Manage Network Connections** and right clicking either the *Wireless Internet Connection* or *Local Area Connection* - when I go to the Properties button, there is no **Sharing** tab to allow me to tick two boxes to allow me to connect my XBox and laptop.

I have also attempted to bridge the two connections, then connect the XBox. However, when I test the connection on the XBox I keep getting 'Test failed'.

Comment: Are you trying to connect the XBox wirelessly, or with a wire, to the notebook?